# Combining variables in r

Tags: r

I've got a dataset like the following.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
T_A_01_F_1 T_A_02_F_1 T_A_03_F_1 T_A_01_F_2 T_A_02_F_2 T_A_03_F_2 T_A_01_U_1 T_A_02_U_1 T_A_03_U_1 T_A_01_U_2 T_A_02_U_2 T_A_03_U_2 T_B_01_F_1 T_B_02_F_1 T_B_03_F_1 T_B_01_F_2 T_B_02_F_2 T_B_03_F_2 T_B_01_U_1 T_B_02_U_1 T_B_03_U_1 T_B_01_U_2 T_B_02_U_2 T_B_03_U_2
1 2 3 NA NA NA 2 2 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 2 5 NA NA NA 1 3 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 3 3 NA NA NA 2 1 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 4 5 NA NA NA 6 3 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA NA NA 4 3 5 NA NA NA 4 3 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA NA NA 4 4 5 NA NA NA 2 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA NA NA 3 1 4 NA NA NA 2 1 7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA NA NA 2 1 6 NA NA NA 3 3 6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 1 1 NA NA NA 2 3 1 NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 1 1 NA NA NA 3 2 2 NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 2 1 NA NA NA 4 2 1 NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 5 4 NA NA NA 6 1 4 NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 2 2 NA NA NA 1 2 5
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 5 4 4 NA NA NA 3 3 5
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 5 4 4 NA NA NA 1 3 5
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 5 1 3 NA NA NA 7 5 1
")
```

In this case its a 2x2x2 mixed design with "T" being the variable of interest with 3 items, "A" and "B" the between factor, "F" and "U" the within factor and "1" and "2" the between factor. I'd like to reduce the dataset, so that I can compute a cronbachs alpha.
As every Person either got A or B and either 1 or 2 I'd like to combine those items, so that I only have the items T_01_F, T_01_U, T_02_F, T_02_U, T_03_F, T_03_U

I could do this by hand, but does somebody know a quick command with which I could do that?

Thank you so much in advance!!

best, Nash

Comment: What do you mean by saying you'd like to 'combine' those items? Do you mean **sum** or **string together**?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a combination of `pivot_longer()` and `separate()` might work since all your column names appear to share the same structure.

```
library(tidyverse)
df<- df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = T_A_01_F_1:T_B_03_U_2) %>% 
  separate(col = name, sep = "_", into = c("t", "a_b", "number" , "within", "between"))
```